# Why "Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition" is not Compiling a Simple C++ Program?

Tags: visual-c++-2008-express

Without wasting your time a short description is important to Describe the Problem.
It is not compiling the Following Program with the error message that example.exe is not found when I tried to Build it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    string name, surname;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter your surname: ";
    cin >> surname;
    cout << "Welcome " << name << " " << surname;
 return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working on my end when I try to build it using GCC Compiler in Visual C++.
Note: Other C++ Compilers need you to to declare the main function by using

> int main()
> and you must have to create a header file main.h and include all libraries that you want to use.
> as I show you in my example of code. Try this code it should work on your end as well. Just you need to create an extra header file main.h and include iostream
> and string in it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;
main()
{
    string name, surname;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter your surname: ";
    cin >> surname;
    cout << "Welcome " << name << " " << surname;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working but also string data type is not defined and why I must use char instead of string? 
This is not possible to use GCC in Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition?

Comment: @Arnold-Baba It is possible to use GCC in Visual C++ 2008 and to do this follow the https://stackoverflow.com/a/7503295/11545930

Comment: Thank you I will try

Comment: @Arnold-Baba Also you can create a header file and Include any libraries you want to use. For example: #include <iostream> and #include <string>